# Ферзь на шахматной доске

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Есть задача :

Мне нужно расставить семь Ферзей на шахматной доске по таким клеткам, чтобы они не могли рубить друг-друга.

Каков алгоритм выполнения данной задачи?

Comment: я знаю, но не могу написать код , можете подсказать как пишется этот код

Comment: напишите словами, то как "вы знаете", а дальше разберемся) Только сразу в вопрос ваш алгоритм

Comment: Это стандартная "олимпиадная" задача. Возьмите алгоритм для 8 ферзей и остановитесь на седьмом.

Comment: в сети полно готовых решений. таких как это https://codepen.io/mostafabahri/pen/bwEZGY или это https://github.com/vderyagin/eight_queens_puzzle